# pysqlcipher installation - SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, sqlite, sqlcipher

I have Python 3.4.2, and I try to install **pysqlcipher** on my PC with windows 8.
After having entered the code below in my command prompt:

```
git clone https://github.com/leapcode/pysqlcipher/
cd pysqlcipher
python setup.py build_sqlcipher
```

I’m getting the following error:

```
  File "setup.py", line 64
    print "CFLAGS", os.environ['CFLAGS']
                 ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

It seems to be a problem with print. I have *Python 3.4.2*, and the print syntax used here corresponds to *Python 2.X*. I have done lot of searching but I haven’t found any solution.

**Does someone know how to install pysqlcipher with Python 3.4.2?**

Thank you for your help!

**PS:** I have already followed this [tutorial](http://www.jerryrw.com/howtocompile.php) and all things indicated have been accomplished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the code is written for Python 2. Python 3 contains several changes that can make some Python 2 incompatible with Python 3.

[Differences between python 2 and python 3](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3)

You can use the included 2to3 tool to convert the `setup.py` and `cross_bdist_wininst.py` into python 3 compatible code.

Just run `2to3 -w setup.py` and `2to3 -w cross_bdist_wininst.py` to convert the python code. The automatic convert works quite well but it does miss out one conversion that is necessary. Change line 209 in `setup.py`

```
-- if sources is None or type(sources) not in (ListType, TupleType):
++ if sources is None or type(sources) not in (List, Tuple):
```

and remove line 30:

```
-- from types import ListType, TupleType
```

This should then allow you to compile the using `python setup.py build_sqlcipher`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer (I had to add to %PATH% the way \Tools\Scripts to enable 2to3 working)! Now I have a new error :

    `src/connection.h:33:21: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
     #include "sqlite3.h"
                         ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1`

Would you have any idea of the issue?